# How to disappear one checkboxs after it is checked

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a table for booking time, I have put times as checkboxs, checboxs are all from one form, and I wand that user can select one checkbox and after submit the form, checkbox becomes unselectable or disappears from. I tried to validate if data is found on database and then make it disappear or unselecteble, but it was not successful.

my table looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lu4L.jpg

Actually  date and time come from another table on database. This is my  php code for each check bos:

```
echo"
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['time1']."'>
<p>". $row['day1'] ,"</p><br/>". $row['time1'] ."
```

can you please help me :-\

Comment: I am not understanding the logic here. The user can see the form even after submitting? If you want the checkbox to disappear after selecting it (before submitting) it can be easily hide by javascript.

Comment: I whant that only one checkbox disappears or becomes unselectable. Each chechbox is a time, that user can reserve for visiting! So I want after submitting only one checkbox becomes unavailble..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right you meant something like this?

```
if($_POST['datetime'] != ($row['day1'] . "   " . $row['time1'])) {
    echo"
    <input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['time1']."' disabled>
    <p>". $row['day1'] ,"</p><br/>". $row['time1'] ."
    // etc
} else {
    echo"
    <input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['time1']."'>
    <p>". $row['day1'] ,"</p><br/>". $row['time1'] ."
}
```

Comment: Than you. It shows that checkbox has been disabled, but it doesn't recognize 'datetime', because this information are from different table on mysql! So I have connection only to the table where this dates are from. Maybe if you take a look at my code, you get my purpose.


Date and time for checkbox are from   **calendar** database and **datetime** table.But the booked time will be stored on another database  named **College** and **studens** table. So I have to datetime, one is a table and other one is just a row from **student** .

Comment: I got this error:

Notice: Undefined index: datetime in C:\xampp\htdocs\form.php on line 98  


    and here is line 98:
    
    if($_POST['datetime'] != ($row['day1'] . "   " . $row['time1'])) {
        echo"
        <input type='radio' name='datetime' value='". $row['day1']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['time1']."' disabled>
        <p>". $row['day1'] ,"</p><br/>". $row['time1'] ."";
    }